# What is the best way to make a resizable image with buttons in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, button, resize

I am trying to place buttons on a resizable image in Flutter but I am having trouble figuring out how to keep the buttons in their relative position on the image.  In other words, I want to create a zoomable image with buttons that lock their position to a particular point on the image. For example, let's say image is the following image of buttons on a control panel where each button has a unique function: [image]

As the buttons are currently laid out very close together it would be difficult for a user to press a single button. I would like the user to be able to zoom in to the image like so:
[image]

and have all the buttons working, maintaining their original function.  Is there a best practice for designing something like this or are there multiple options?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by wrapping Image widget that contained the buttons with an InteractiveViewer widget:

```
    Expanded(
      child: InteractiveViewer(
        boundaryMargin: EdgeInsets.all(100),
        minScale: 0.1,
        maxScale: 1.6,
          child: Container(
```